# how can i close the scanner object within a newly created thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a timed input program where the user has to input an integer every 5 seconds however the code below only works if the user answers them all in time but in the case that a user misses an input the scanner objects created by each new thread is left open which is why when the input was 7 it was not read by the scanner object and i was wondering if there is anyway i can close the scanner object that each thread creates

import java.util.*;

public class ex4{

```
private static class Score {
    public Integer maxScore;
    public Integer totalAttempts;
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final Score score = new Score();
    //score.maxScore = 1;
    score.maxScore = 0;
    score.totalAttempts =0;

    System.out.println("Initial maxScore: " + score.maxScore);
    while(score.totalAttempts<10) {
    Thread student = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            score.totalAttempts++;
            System.out.print(">");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int temp =in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("you entered:"+temp);
            score.maxScore+= temp;
        }
    };

    student.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    student.interrupt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Result maxScore: " + score.maxScore);
}
```

}

```
whenever the user misses the 5 second window the scanner objects stack up so the output looks like this
```

```
Initial maxScore: 0
>5
you entered:5

>
>6
3
>
6
you entered:6
you entered:6
you entered:3

>
>7

>
>
>
>
Result maxScore: 20
```

Comment: why close the scanner? Just exit your loop

Comment: I would have the thread notify the main thread somehow, and use the scanner there. Do not close any scanner that is built on System.in. If you close the scanner, System.in will close also. And you can't reopen System.in.